# get swipe count needed from given arraylist

Tags: java, algorithm

i have list say 891234567 so in this i need 2 rotation or 51234 then its 1 rotation . how to find swipe count requries for given list . Any example will do

```
 public int count(arraylist){
 for(int i = 0 ; i < arraylist.size,i++)
 if(arraylist.get(i)> array.get(i+1)){
     }
  else{
    }

}
```

Comment: idk if it's just me, but this is plain incomprehensible to me. Pls clarify

Comment: Are those list always sorted like this?

Comment: Please provide more information or more examples, it very unclear ...

Comment: I think I get what he's trying to achieve. having 891234567 he wants to get 12345678 as a result. he thought he therefore needs to go through the for loop twice to achieve it.

Comment: @pacholik ya it can be like 54321 then count will be 5 or 35412 count will be 3

Comment: You mean 34512 --> count = 3?

Comment: So are you just trying to find position of **1**?

Comment: 35412 -> 12345 so i have to swipw 354 means 3 swipes requries

Comment: In your question, can you further clarify what you mean by swipe count? Is it the number of rotations on a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm getting it right, this should do :

```
public int count(ArrayList<Integer> arraylist)
{
    int count = 0;
    int flag = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < arraylist.size() - 1; i++)
    if(arraylist.get(i) > arraylist.get(i+1))
    {
        count++;
        flag = 1;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        count++;
    }
    if(flag == 0)
    {
        count = 0;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Alternatively you can try this solution :

```
public int count(ArrayList<Integer> arraylist)
{
    int a = Collections.min(arraylist);
    int count = arraylist.indexOf(a);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: this will failed in 32145

Comment: In this case what is the answer that you are expecting ?

Answer (score 1):

Finds position of **1**

```
arraylist.indexOf(1);
```

If I get it right, then this is all you need.

Comment: by this will get 1st pos value

Comment: more precisely, find position of the minimum element

Answer (score 0):

based on my comment I'm just guessing what you tried to achieve.

I'm not sure if you thought about a for loop on purpose (is it a school exercise??) or if you just didn't know any better.

The easiest way would be to do a simple (I'm assuming you have a list of integers):

```
Collections.sort(arraylist);
```